# The Z manifold and the corresponding Gepner and LG models

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, calabi-yau, mirror-symmetry

Let $\mathscr{T}$ be a product of three tori $\mathscr{T}_1 \times \mathscr{T}_2 \times \mathscr{T}_3$ with each torus formed by making the identifications $z_i \simeq z_i+1 \simeq z_i + \omega^{1/2}, \omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Then, we divide $\mathscr{T}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_3$ generated by $z_i \mapsto \omega z_i$ and get the orbifold $\mathscr{Z}$.
This is called the $\mathscr{Z}$ manifold.

According to page 3 of [Candelas.et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9304045), the $\mathscr{Z}$ manifold can be identified with $1^9$ Gepner model and LG model obtained by the polynomial $\sum_{k=1}^9 y_k^3$.

Why these three can be identified ?
And, are there any good references ?

Any comments welcome !
Thank you.

Comment: Stuff like this is covered in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9702155

Comment: The 1^9 is identified with LG potential with powers in 9 variables of (1+2) for c=9 model generated by (1,1...1) (9 times) (1+2, 1+2....,1+2). This minimal model has discrete group of symmetries generated by combination of 3 with Z_{P+2}×Z_{P+2}×Z_{P+2} with P=1 in P^2×P^2×P^2 which gives you what is desired as a degree 3 hom. in P^2 is necessarily of genus 1 I.e. torus.

Comment: This type of construction was first used by Greene, Vafa and Warner in a 1988 or 89 paper on Calabi Yau and Renormalization group flows.